# Can I create crossplatform Xamarin apps by coding in Windows and reusing the source code OSX?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm thinking about learning Xamarin Forms and I'm curious about cross platform development, starting with a PC and Visual Studio. Android apps, of course, can be compiled on a PC.

Crossplatform discussions then usually continue with compiling iOS apps using the same source code on a network connected Macs. (I've also read about coding iOS apps directly on a Mac via Xamarin Studio or VS2017.)

I'm wondering whether I could code and test a Xamarin Forms Android app on a PC and then later copy and compile (some of?) the code on a Mac with Xamarin Studio--no network connections? Could I code on the PC, place the source code in a shared repository, clone the code to a repository on a Mac, and create an iOS app?

Comment: Since both respondents agreed on the answer, I'll accept the first. I do, though, thank both of you for taking the time to respond ... Somehow it seems to me like this way of making a crossplatform app will be easier than setting up the Mac like a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could build the Android app with VS and the iOS App with XS/VSMac, sharing the same core Forms project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can compile the same Xamarin source code on Mac or Windows. Xamarin uses Mono which isn't dependent on Windows.